# PHP and Wordpress + Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

I'm currently running a shop with **WooCommerce** and I need my website to use 4 different languages.
I used **Polylang** free plugin to translate my website.

I'm using WooCommerce REST API to send items to the website and it is working just fine via .json files. I can send 100 products at once with name, description, price, sizes, shapes, colors, etc.

My issue here is that I need the NAME and the DESCRIPTION of the product translated. So I need to generate a .json file with let's say: English, Spanish and French, with their NAMES and DESCRIPTION and send the correct file to the correct language. My concern is that I don't know how and if that's possible.

My website's main language is Portuguese and if I send a .json file it creates my product with all its information. The only way I can create a product on other languages is manually, but the goal here is to:

- send a .json file to the website with 4 different languages;
- or send 4 different files for each language.

I guess there is Polylang API but I don't really know which part to use or how to use it in this case.

Best regards,
Hugo

Answer (score 0):

**Polylang** (free) does not expose Rest API, it's only available in **Polylang Pro** version. You might also need **Polylang for WooCommerce** to piece it all together.

Technically you can use **WooCommerce** + **Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration** (does not provide REST API) and implement your own WooCommerce + Polylang REST API "glue" plugin, but it's not an easy task, and I would only recommend this route for very experienced developer.

Comment: "Technically you can use WooCommerce + Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration (does not provide REST API) and implement your own WooCommerce + Polylang REST API "glue" plugin, but it's not an easy task, and I would only recommend this route for very experienced developer."

That is the thing I'm trying to do. Glueing code to implement the translations.
I'm already using the plugins you mentioned.